# Can I change the color for interpolated string expressions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

Interpolated string expressions in C# could be great. But the default color (black) does not help the brain to scan over the text easily. The default string color is red. This results in the brain being more confused than it should be, rendering this feature less effective than it should be - at least for me.

[image: Example of interpolated string expressions in a code generator app]

Can I change the color of interpolated string expressions in Visual Studio? 
I would be happy if I could set it to a dark red color. Thus not confusing, but still easily noticeable.

Via Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors one can define the colors of strings and verbatim strings, but not for interpolated string expressions.

Edit: The comment of Jeff Mercado made me realize that the color of all code components would have to be defined for interpolated string expressions. This could be avoided if one could define a **hue** (i.e. not a color) for interpolated string expressions.

Edit: Added a code generator snippet to show an example of the sea of tokens where the eyes become lost and one can not easily enough identify the generated strings from the actual code:
[image]

Comment: The expressions are colored the way each of the components of the expressions are normally colored. If you want them to stand out more, you need to change the colors of the corresponding components.

Comment: @JeffMercado: the components you refer to are all the other code (i.e. back). I don't want to change all of my code to a dark red color. I understand what you are saying. My question is related to the unfortunate issue that jumping from black to red in a block of a semantically coherent thingy - i.e. an interpolated string - is not easy for the brain to parse. Similar colors are more fruitful. I'm asking for an improvement of the current state.

Comment: @JeffMercado: The issue of having to define custom colors for all the existing components could be solved by providing a hue (i.e. not a color) for interpolated string expressions.

Comment: You should look at the expressions found in the interpolated strings differently. They are just that, expressions, and they are in "holes" of the string. Unfortunately they haven't added the ability to make these expressions more distinguishable as far as I know.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Yes, the expressions are holes in the string. Better coloring would make them more productive. It's just the way the brain works. At the end of the day, the stuff that wins us is the stuff that is sophisticated enough - the inner workings of the human brain included :-)

Comment: You'd have to either create or find a VS Extension that changes the color of interpolated expressions. You can use the code from open-source tools with interpolated strings refactorings like [Refactoring Essentials](https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials)  or [Code Cracker](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker) as a strating point.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the colors under the Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors preferences menu and discovered that the inside color of the interpolated string (e.g. the "name" in "{name}") is tied to the "Identifier" item, while the color of the brackets is tied to the "Punctuation" item. So no, it doesn't look like you can change the color of interpolated strings without making the rest of your code totally wacky.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good suggestion. The best ways to turn a suggestion into a feature in Visual Studio are:

- Send-a-Smile if the suggestion stands on it's own. This could
  qualify, but one-off suggestions still face challenges. Several
  similar suggestions will be noticed.
- [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) - which will need reasonable community support to get
  attention.
- Connect - which is not the best route for suggestions; it's intended
  for bugs and is filtered significantly before decision-makers see it.
- Reply to team blog posts.

A great feature suggestion explains what you want and why you want it. If you have implementation ideas, it doesn't hurt to separate them from the suggestion itself. The solution you propose may have been discussed and rejected, but focusing on the problem itself is still productive.

Include your email; follow-up discussions can help clarify your intentions. Some good suggestions are lost because of a typo, or incompatible vocabulary. The feature may already exist but be undiscoverable; in that case a different problem needs to be fixed. Your follow-up feedback on why the solution provided isn't adequate may be very helpful.

If you've gone down this road in the past and received no satisfaction, try again. Things change; I see user feedback being taken very seriously by Visual Studio.